# Checking multiple conditions against list within a list

Tags: pandas, list, conditional-statements

I am trying to filter out entities from sample dataset below based on two conditions i.e if their values are between 0-180 or 180-360.. and plan to create two separate lists of such entities..
my df is;

```
Entityname Value
A          200
A          240
A          330
B          15
B          120
C          190
C          220
```

expected Output:

```
Entities_1=['A','C']
Entities_2=['B']
```

Below is what I have been trying..

```
Entities_1=[]
Entities_2=[]

for name in df.Entityname:
    if df.Value > 0 & df.Value < 180:
        Entities_1.append(name)
    else:
        if df.Value > 180 & df.Value < 360:
            Entities_2.append(name)
```

getting some errors on above and not sure if this is the right way forward..
any help would be appreciated please!..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [pandas.Series.between()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) and boolean indexing.

```py
Entities_1 = df.loc[df['Value'].between(0, 180), 'Entityname'].unique().tolist()
Entities_2 = df.loc[df['Value'].between(180, 360), 'Entityname'].unique().tolist()
```

```
# print(Entities_1)
['B']

# print(Entities_2)
['A', 'C']
```